# Django-vimeo 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, django-models, vimeo

Model structure is like below:

```
class Video(models.Model):
video_header = models.CharField(max_length=350, verbose_name="Video Başlığı", blank=False, null=False)
video_description = models.TextField(verbose_name="Video Açıklaması", blank=False, null=False)
date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Oluşturma Tarihi", blank=False, null=False)
video = fields.VimeoField(null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.video_header

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Video İçeriği"
    verbose_name_plural = "Video İçerikleri"
```

When I click on any video object which created in django admin to edit it, get " 'NoneType' object is not iterable " error. But actually there is an object and it is not "None" when I look at database. So it seems like meanless to me. Could you please help me to get through this problem.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9hU5.png)

[Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZnYQ.png)

Comment: can you share the full TraceBack

Comment: Edited the post with screenshots